# Lookup field not working in Chrome for iPad using full Salesforce version

Tags: chrome

When I access the full version of Salesforce via Chrome for iPad I am not able to use the lookup field. When I click on the glass, it opens a new tab and I can search for what you need but, when I select my item, it just sits there and does nothing. It does not populate the field you were performing the lookup on.

If I use Safari everything works fine, although not close the search window.

Any suggestions for this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/apex/answers?id=90630000000hstoAAA) and I've run into many times.

Comment: Dear Gaurav, 
I try this solution, but not resolve the problem.

Thanks

Comment: There is actually no workaround at least as far as I know. I pointed out the link so that you're aware of this known issue.